# Creating a mobile-friendly widget on a non-mobile-friendly page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

#### Quick background:

I'm trying to make a mobile-friendly widget. My customers have non-mobile friendly pages, and this isn't likely to change anytime soon.

#### Attempted solution:

I figured this wouldn't be so bad. Just remove the widget from the page flow by using `position:fixed`, insert a viewport meta tag, and presto! ...right?
[See this here fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/kg4dckL8/)

#### The Problem:

The attempted a solution breaks on some mobile devices. When using a co-worker's phone, they were able to scroll *away* from the supposedly `position:fixed` element! (Phone in question is Android 4 or 5, so it's not the 2.1-2.3 bug.) I'm pretty sure this same behavior occurs on iPhones.

Essentially, it seems to be behaving as though it were `position:absolute` on the top-left corner of the page.

#### Attempted Solution Details:

I start by appending the viewport meta tag with javascript:

```
$('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>');
```

Let's just assume a very basic HTML template:

```
<html>
    ...
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="modal">
            <div class="content">...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</html>
```

and following CSS:

```
.hide-overflow {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden; /* Not that this does anything */
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: table;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.modal {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.content {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .overlay * {
        max-width: 100%;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .content {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

Of course, I didn't think this would be enough. I also added the following javascript to prevent scrolling on the `<body>` and outer-most `<div>` element:

```
// This only shows up when the widget is activated--it's removed on deactivation.
$('body').addClass('hide-overflow');// Just adds overflow:hidden, in case you forgot ;)
$('body > div').addClass('hide-overflow');
```

On my phone's (Galaxy <strike>Tablet</strike> Note) default browser, this works great! No problems! As mentioned before, on iPhones, questionable Android devices, etc., you can scroll away from the `position:fixed` element as though it were actually `position: absolute`. How do I get `position:fixed` to work?

Comment: Do you have a demo? Screenshot? Hard for me to understand what you are trying to accomplish with position:fixed;

Comment: @TroyThompson Not allowed to show the product during development, but let me see if I can't whip up a fiddle for you.

Comment: @TroyThompson It took a bit, but I'm all done: http://jsfiddle.net/kg4dckL8/

Comment: I only have an iPad to use to try to replicate the error, but I need to charge it. Until then, I would suggest a couple things. 1. I think its important to also set overflow: hidden on the html tag. 2. I try to avoid position:fixed elements when mobile is concerned. Is there any way you could just position:absolute; and get the width:100%; and height:100%; on the overlay?

Comment: @TroyThompson The problem is that this will live on non-mobile-friendly pages. It needs to "escape" the DOM and overlay on top of the page. Also, the fact that `position:fixed` is behaving like `position:absolute` _is_ the problem.

Comment: I see - well I will have access to some other devices in a bit, I'll take a look again later today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was a bit simpler than I'd thought. Using javascript, I was already appending my `hide-overflow` class to the body and first div element. That class looked like this:

```
.hide-overflow {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

What fixed my problem was changing it to the following:

```
.hide-overflow {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box !important;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box !important;
    box-sizing: border-box !important;
}
```

That's it! Just add this class to the `<body>` tag when the widget shows, and remove it when the widget is hidden.

[Here's the working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/kg4dckL8/1/)